# Use Google Places nearbySearch function in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

In Web API, use the `nearbySearch` function will return the results nearby the specific coordinate.

But I cannot find a similar function in iOS SDK.

I think the worst way is using REST API likes
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=22.979468,112.544345&radius=100&key=API_KEY` by Alamofire

But I have another problem, I don't know how to restrict my API key for iOS REST API only.

I tried to set it for iOS Application but it does not work.

Please give me some idea, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply iOS app restriction on web service API key. The only supported restrictions for web services are IP address restrictions. This supposes that you are executing web service requests from your backend server and restrict an API key with IP address of your backend server.

In case of mobile iOS app that means you should create an intermediate server to execute web services and pass responses back to your app in order to protect an API key that you use with web service.

There is a feature request in the Google issue tracker to add nearby search as a part of Places API for iOS:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830334

Feel free to star this feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Hope this resolves your doubt.